# Add a label to the first UITableViewCell row while reusing cells

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

Is it possible to add a label to a UITableViewCell while reusing cells? This is the code I have been trying but when I scroll down and the cells get reused my label moves around. I just want the label in the very first row at all times, but I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I know I can not reuse the cells and it will work but I would like to reuse the cells. Please help me figure this out. Thank you very much...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

        UILabel* Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,2, 62, 23)];

        [Label setText:@"Text"];

        [cell addSubview:Label]; 

        [Label release];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out. I made the 1st row not reusable.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellsToBeReused = @"CellsToBeReused";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellsToBeReused];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellsToBeReused] autorelease]; 
    }
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *first_Cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
        UILabel* Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,2, 62, 23)];
        [Label setText:@"Text"];
        Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [first_Cell.contentView addSubview:Label];
        [Label release];
        return first_Cell;        
    } else  {
        return cell;        
    }
}
```